# How to Get datablock default where that oracle forms generate with Enter-query action

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am working with oracle forms 6i.

Simply I am using database block with these items :

```
Employees:    employee_id , job_id , department_id , manager_id
```

*note: employees is the data-block name .*

For example: when end user click enter-query button and write 50 in `department_id` item and then click execute-query button; data block will return all employees who are in department 50.

My question is : **How can I get the WHERE CLAUSE that oracle forms generate when returned desired data?...**

I used this code in `pre-query trigger`

```
:parameters.whr:=get_block_property('employees',default_where);
```

But it returned no results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're *close*, but not *close enough*. It is the `GET_BLOCK_PROPERTY` you need, but use its `LAST_QUERY` parameter. It will return SQL statement of the last query in the specified block.

Alternatively, use system variable `:SYSTEM.LAST_QUERY` (returns the same result).

Here's an example( the following code might be put in `KEY-EXEQRY` trigger of `employees` block ):

```
declare
  l_lastq          varchar2(4000);
  l_where_position number;
  l_where_clause   varchar2(4000);
begin
  execute_query;
  l_lastq := :system.last_query;
  l_where_position := instr(lower(l_lastq), 'where');

  if l_where_position > 0 then
     l_where_clause := substr(l_lastq, l_where_position, length(l_lastq));
     message('WHERE clause: ' || l_where_clause);
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Congratulations dear friend for such a nice solution.

Comment: Excellent answer, you helped me a lot !!
In my case I had to use `LAST_QUERY` of the Block since, as it had a relation, `:SYSTEM.LAST_QUERY` brought me the query of the detail block.

Comment: I'm glad if it helped, @Cero.